# Segmentary fault with pointer array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I get Segmentary fault with this code:

```
 #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int* arrayCreate(int length){
        int *ew[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            *(ew[i])=i;
        }
    
        return ew[0];
    }
    
    int main(){
        int *ptr=arrayCreate(7);
        cout << *ptr << endl;
    }
```

And when I tried to change this line

```
int *ew[length];
```

into

```
int *ew = new int[length];
```

I have error < indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid) >

Any one please explain the difference between these two declaration, why I get segmentary fault and how to fix it?

Comment: Your concept of pointers, addresses, and values are muddled up. You need a C primer.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, you allocate array of pointers on the stack and return an element of that array - which is dead once the function finishes. Accessing this return value means undefined behaviour.

In the second version, you create array *of ints* (not pointers) on the heap. Thus the syntax error.

What you want is

```
int* arrayCreate(int length){
    int* ew = new int[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        ew[i]=i;
    }

    return ew;
}
```

Or better yet, don't use `new[]`, use `std::vector`, which manages memory for you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> //for std::iota
std::vector<int> arrayCreate(int length){
    std::vector<int> v (length);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0); //you can use your loop as well
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that `int *ew[length];` is a VLA which doesn't conform to standard C++.

Comment: I don't get the ew[i]=i;   ew is a pointer array, which is int*, how can we assign an integer to a pointer of integer?

Comment: @Kas `int* ew` is not a pointer array. It is a single pointer to `int`.

Comment: @Kas The type of variable can never be to the right of `=`. When you have `int* ew [10]`, type of `ew` is *array of 10 pointers to int*. When you have `int* ew`, the type is *pointer to int*. `new[]` allocates an array on the heap and returns pointer to the first element of that array.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int *ew[length];
> ```

Problem 1: The size of an array variable must be compile time constant. `length` is not a compile time constant. Thus, the program is ill-formed.

> how to fix it?

If you need an array with dynamic size, you need to allocate dynamically. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector`.

---

> why I get segmentary fault

Observation: The pointers in `ew` have indeterminate values. They don't point to any valid object.

> ```
> *(ew[i])=i;
> ```

Problem 2: You indirect through a pointer stored in the array. Since you're indirecting through an invalid pointer, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Ask yourself: What `int` object was `ew[i]` supposed to be pointing to?

> how to fix it?

Don't read indeterminate values, and don't indirect through invalid pointers.

---

> ```
> int *ew = new int[length];
> ```

Here, you create a dynamic array of integers. Array of integers is not an array of pointers. `ew` is a pointer to an integer. `ew` is not a pointer to a pointer.

> ```
> *(ew[i])=i;
> ```

Here, you indirect through `ew` to access `i`th successor sibling, and then indirect through that sibling. But the first indirection results in an `int` object and you cannot indirect through an `int`.

> how to fix it?

Don't try to indirect through an `int`.

> Any one please explain the difference between these two declaration

`int *ew[length]` is an ill-formed and uninitialised array of pointers to `int`. `int* ew` is a single pointer to an `int`, in this case initialised with the address of a first element of a dynamic array of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

To get memory for your array in C++ you should write:

`int *ew = new int[length];`

To return the pointer you should write:

`return ew;`

This means you return pointer to the beginning of array. It should be mentioned that `a[i]` <=> `*(a + i)`. You can't write `*(ew[i]) = i;` to assign, but `ew[i] = i;` will work.

It should also be said that usage of raw pointers is deprecated in modern c++.